# Faker в Laravel генерирует тексты и слова на латинском

Tags: laravel, laravel5, seed

Имена адреса и тд. все создается на заданном языке при создании, но текста и слова исключительно на латинском в чем проблема не могу найти решения?

```
$faker = Faker::create('ru_RU');
$text = $faker->word;

//result - "dignissimos"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Латинскими, потому что `word` возвращает слово из Lorem ipsum. Причина, по которой Faker так работает описана тут: [Lorem provider should not be localized](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/pull/394)

Можно получить локализованный текст методом `realText()` и взять из него слово.

*Либо сделать pull-request с новым методом `realWord()` ;)*